# Setting major-mode specific keybindings in emacs

Tags: emacs, key-binding

In my `.emacs` file, I want to add a key binding for a specific major mode (setting `coffee-compile-file` to <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> in coffee-mode).

I've found a lot of instructions on using `local-set-key` and `global-set-key`, so I can easily add this binding once I've opened a file in coffee-mode, but it would be nice for this to be handled by `.emacs`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the mode hook.  `C-h m` shows information about the major mode, usually including what hook(s) it supports; then you do something like

```
(add-hook 'coffee-mode-hook ;; guessing
    '(lambda ()
       (local-set-key "\C-cc" 'coffee-compile-file)))
```

Answer (score 7):

You can define the key in the mode specific map, something like:

```
(add-hook 'coffee-mode-hook
    (lambda ()
        (define-key coffee-mode-map (kbd "C-c c") 'coffee-compile-file)))
```

Or, more cleanly:

```
(eval-after-load "coffee-mode"
    '(define-key coffee-mode-map (kbd "C-c c") 'coffee-compile-file))
```

The second statement causes the key definition to only happen once, whereas the first causes the definition to happen every time `coffee-mode` is enabled (which is overkill).

Comment: FYI: these parens are in the wrong place. This add-hook should read:

`(add-hook 'coffee-mode-hook
    (lambda ()
        (define-key coffee-mode-map (kbd "C-c c") 'coffee-compile-file)))`

Comment: Also, why defining it in a hook ?

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks You're right, defining it in a hook is not as clean as using an `eval-after-load` statement in this case.  I'll update the answer appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

Emacs 24.4 superseded `eval-after-load` with [`with-eval-after-load`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880139/what-is-with-eval-after-load-in-emacs-lisp):

```
** New macro `with-eval-after-load'.
This is like the old `eval-after-load', but better behaved.
```

So the answer should be

```
(with-eval-after-load 'coffee-mode
  (define-key coffee-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'coffee-compile-file)
  (define-key erlang-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-m") 'coffee-make-coffee)
  ;; Add other coffee commands
)
```