# How to re-bind a binding from a major mode

Tags: emacs

I am using org-mode and want to override the local binding of `C-c C-x C-z`, bound to `org-resolve-clocks` by default. The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-Rebinding.html#Init-Rebinding) says

> As described in Local Keymaps, major modes and minor modes can define local keymaps. ... If you wish to change one of these keymaps, you must use the mode hook (see Hooks).

So I have these lines in my `~/.emacs`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-x C-SPC") 'my-function)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-x C-z") 'my-function)

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-x C-z") 'my-function)))
```

The first line binds an unbound key to the function. The second line binds a key already bound in org-mode to the function. The remaining lines define the hook.

I start Emacs anew and describe the keys. `C-c C-x C-SPC` is bound to `my-function` and `C-c C-x C-z` is bound to the default `org-resolve-clocks` in an org buffer and to `my-function` elsewhere. If I run the binding code interactively in an org buffer with `M-:`:

```
(local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-x C-z") 'my-function)
```

then the key is bound to `my-function` and not the default.

I also tried another answer in [this thread on setting major-mode specific keybindings in emacs](https://superuser.com/questions/262980/setting-major-mode-specific-keybindings-in-emacs) and it failed:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'org-mode
  '(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-x C-SPC") 'my-function)
)
```

I am running Emacs 25.3 (9.0).

How can I override a binding in set in a major mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind your function in org-mode using `define-key`:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-x C-z") 'my-function)
```

It will override any global bindings and work only in an org-mode buffer.